# How to co-debug in Visual Studio Code Live Share?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-liveshare

I am using the [Live Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/liveshare/)-Extension in Visual Studio Code to code in python together with a friend. It works just fine, however when one of us starts debugging the code, the program only runs on my PC (I am the host). My friend only sees the debug log terminal.

Is it possible to run/debug the program so that both participants actually see it?

Comment: so the participant doesn't have the host's Debug View shared to them? can you still reproduce this behaviour? does anything in [the related docs for Co-Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/use/codebug-visual-studio-code) help?